# Why can I not get the selected value in a dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

NET MVC 1.0.

I use

```
ViewData["DeptID"] = new SelectList(DeptID, "ID", "Name", course.DeptID);
```

where I am passing the selected value `DeptID` as forth parameter, but it doesn't work.  When I debug, then the above selection list is correct with the selected value.

I use

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("DeptID", (SelectList)ViewData["DeptID"]) %>
```

in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just using:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("DeptID") %>
```

Here is an [article](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist-and-html-attributes/) about it.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "If i do debug then also above Selection list is correct with selected value", are you saying this works in debug mode but does not work in release, or are you saying that you see the correct value in the 4th parameter but it still does not appear to selct the item in the list?

One thing to check, what types are the 1st and 4th parameters (`DeptID` and `course.DeptID`)? These will need to be compatible - e.g. if `DeptID` is a collection of strings then `course.DeptID` will need to be a string.

Comment: well course is an object & course.DeptID is an int value. but this is not a probject as it require an object.
In debug, ViewData["DeptID"] shows selected value true for one row.
but when html page render it there is no option with selected="Selected" attribute. I also tried as Mike Roosa said.